# Reclaim ownership of a YouTube account

Tags: youtube

I opened a YouTube account for my department (middle school history) with a throw away email that I no longer have access to. I have been trying for the past 18 months to reset the password, because one of the new teachers gave the password to a student who I believe went in and probably changed it because none of our usual passwords work.

It is not connected to an email account. Our district is now a GAFE district and has Google accounts but when I went in to connect it to mine that is when I found the password didn't work.

The channel has 45 videos, all student projects, so clearly it's a school account. I have searched and searched for a solution and tried every combination of solutions on the YouTube/Google help page/forums.

I guess I could flag three videos and they would delete it; but short of that is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that whoever hijacked the YouTube account attached said account to their own Google+ profile? The YouTube account seems old enough to have that happen to it as it likely was not attached to a Google+ account when you made the YouTube account.

If so, that means it's attached to another persons email account (or Google+ account) that may be the student or hijacker in question. You would need to contact Google and see if they can reattach your Google+ to the YouTube account, but I don't know how they could verify that.

I've worked in customer service. If it's clear the YouTube channel is on the topic of your employer, then you or someone in management would need to prove they are who they say they are to Google (normally by faxing a copy of their drivers license to the service provider). Then you could be able to retain the account based on copyright alone as the channel is using your employers copyrighted information. If not, you should AT LEAST be able to close the YouTube channel or get the videos removed by filing a copyright infringement report. Then start a new channel and take better care of your security next time around.

Comment: A faxed copy of a driver's licence still would not prove that the person belongs to the school involved.